How to change the default port number for mysqld
I am running mysqld v8 on Ubuntu.  The service starts via systemctl.
I need to change the default port number but searching the canonical locations (e.g. my.cnf) the port number is not set any any instance of that file.
Based upon the docs I can change the port on the command line for mysqld but I am not seeing how to change it for systemctl.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/using-systemd.html#systemd-multiple-mysql-instances. Are you saying you don't have /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf?

FYI this probably belongs on https://serverfault.com/ or [ubuntu.se]

That would be dba.stackexchange.com

In the file where your configuration is (possibly /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf) you should have a section of
[mysqld]

inside this section make sure you have something like
port        = <your number here>


I do have that file and the port line is commented out.  I was looking for my.cnf and not mysqld.cnf.

I uncommented the line, changed the port number and restarted the service and it is now running on the new port.  Thank you!

@Notamachine happy to help!

It's a system variable. Its name is port.
